# How to incorporate time string to classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning

One of the columns in my dataset looks like the following:

[image]

I'm wondering what the best practice is to incorporate this information into the classifier models.

Please help me with it. The project is done in python with the Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate string to seconds and use it as one of the features:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['25m 34s', '1m', '22s'], columns=['game_length'])
df['game_length_seconds'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['game_length']).apply(lambda x: x.seconds)

>>> df

  game_length  game_length_seconds
0     25m 34s                 1534
1          1m                   60
2         22s                   22
```

Comment: I tried this one before. It gave an error like this : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'

Comment: My bad. `seconds` is an attribute of the single `timedelta` object. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a lambda function to map that column:

```
def duration_from_epoc(time:str):
    # converts string to datetime and in this case the following line would result in 1900-01-01 00:25:28
    date_time = datetime.strptime(time, "%Mm %Ss")

    # calculate duration from epoc / start datetime. here you can CHANGE your starting time
    date_time_from = datetime(1970,1,1)

    # returns delta total seconds
    return (date_time - date_time_from).total_seconds()
```

Then you can call,
`df["game_length"].map(duration_from_epoc)`

For example, the result of '**25m 28s**' (str) would be **-2208987272.0** (float)

Overall, the solution is calculating seconds from a standard date time to your date time (calculated from string form of duration). Caution that "25m 28s" converts to 1900-01-01 00:25:28 datetime object.

At the end, I would say that instead of saving duration, try to save start and end time of each game play so that you can always calculate duration on the go.